# JavaScript syntax with server-side Url.Content

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

```
currentObject = someValue;
var src = '<%=Url.Content("~/Content/images/locations/" + currentObject + ".jpg")%>';
```

But since Url.Content is in ', the currentObject is 'currentObject', and not its value.

How to write the above code with currentObject's value, not name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are mixing .NET(Im guessing its .NET) and javascript.

```
currentObject = someValue;
var src = '<%=Url.Content("~/Content/images/locations/")%>' + currentObject + '.jpg';
```

will get your src.

Answer (score 1):

Try change your code to:

```
currentObject = someValue;
var src = <%=Url.Content("~/Content/images/locations/")%> + currentObject + ".jpg";
```